# Google Cloud Platform Project-ID wrong format

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google

I`m using Google cloud platform and now I want to use the API. I used the option on their [website](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/list#try-it) to try API-Calls but everytime i give in my Project-ID it get this as a response

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidParameter",
    "message": "Invalid value ' <myProject-id>'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\\.)*(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))'",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "project"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid value ' <myProject-id>'. Values must match the following regular expression: '(?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\\.)*(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?))'"
 }
}
```

I got my Project-ID by going to my project settings en there I saw Project-id: so I used that ID, is this the wrong ID maybe?

[project-id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtRnZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the API call using  [the article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/instances/list#try-it) and it worked fine. I also tested the call using the project number and it worked. Your project ID and project number can be obtained from the Dashboard as explained in this [link](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158840?hl=en). I would suggest trying using an [incognito window](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?source=gsearch&hl=en). If that does not work try with the project number. Your browser might be parsing wrongly some of the characters of your project ID.

Comment: The incognito modus did the job. thank you very much